# Android checkbox array

Tags: android

I have 12 `CheckBox` in an array and I have to check if more than 1 `CheckBox` is checked I have to get toast message "cannot select more than 1 checkbox".

My code:

```
chkArray = new CheckBox[12];
chkArray[0]=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
chkArray[1]=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
chkArray[2]=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
chkArray[3]=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
chkArray[4]=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
```

and so on

```
chkArray[0].setOnClickListener(mListener);
chkArray[1].setOnClickListener(mListener);
chkArray[2].setOnClickListener(mListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is adding a loop in the onCheckedChanged listener where you check each checkbox for true or false. If more than one checkbox is checked (including the last checked checkbox), set that checkbox to false and display the message.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html

Store array of boolean value with index as a key.

put this on click listener of checkbox

```
if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
            //here value with true state
                            //here you can know any one  item is selected

          Toast.makeText(getContext(),"cannot select more than 1 checkbox",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      return;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but it sounds like you want the functionality of radiobuttons instead of checkboxes.

**RadioButton:**

> Radio buttons allow the user to select one option from a set. You should use radio buttons for optional sets that are mutually exclusive.

More information at  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html